# Two accounts made with same email bug - Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have my firebase authentication set to prevent multiple accounts for the same email, but it doesn't seem to be doing that. See following pictures:

[image: firebase console]

[image: firebase accounts]

Has anybody experienced this issue before?

****Edit:** Here's the details for reproducing this bug:

Pretty much the problem boils down to the `updateEmail()` function.

When a user signs up for my app I want to ensure I have an email for the user so searching for that user is easier. The problem is Facebook authentication doesn't ensure the user has an email for the following two reasons:

- The user could have not allowed email permissions.
- The user could have created their Facebook account only using a phone number.

Because of this, my 
login code is somewhat complex but here's a link to my code with comments to explain everything (Note that I'm using custom Facebook/Google buttons which is why I had to manually do some stuff): [Login Gist](https://gist.github.com/MarksCode/988483ba9f373e913d060837259572d1)

If you look at the `func getFBUserData()` and see the comments above it, the bug is happening in the Case 1's first bullet point:

```
// 1) user's facebook does have email. This is common case
//         - in this case, sign them into Firebase
//               - could be that they previously didn't have email but now they do, so update Firebase user's email
```

This is the edge case where for some reason a user first didn't allow email permissions, then changed their minds and allowed them. What's interesting is that the code will still throw the .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse error, but the account will show up in the Firebase console as seen in the picture in the SO question and the following which I just did:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANW89.jpg

Comment: Have you ever changed the setting to 'Allow multiple accounts‘, and back to 'Prevent multiple account' now?

Comment: nope. not that I remember...

Comment: Can you reproduce this right now?  If you create a Facebook and Google account with the same email (Google first, to match the image) does it work?

Comment: @MarksCode thank you for the detailed steps, I am going to circulate this to a few people internally as there's certainly a bug here (even if we intended this behavior, the bug is in how we've documented it)